# Rails; where to put query narrowing interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I've been build web API with Rails.

For this case,
I need to have define some resources for API.
So it's hard to figure out where to put something to narrows query results.

We could do specify things in `AR scope`;

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
end
```

or
with `class method`;

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.published
    where(published: true)
  end
end
```

and `serverside resources` (I use [jsonapi-resource](http://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.10/guide/resources.html));

```
class ContactResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :name_first, :name_last, :full_name
  def full_name
    "#{@model.name_first}, #{@model.name_last}"
  end
  def self.updatable_fields(context)
    super - [:full_name]
  end
  def self.creatable_fields(context)
    super - [:full_name]
  end
end
```

What makes you decide to where to put those type of query narrowing interface.
And what's the difference among those. (Especially `class method` vs `scope` is very confusing.)

Any idea?

Comment: If I have understood jsonapi-resource correctly its basically just a serializer which turns records into JSON. Since what you are doing above is a database scope it belongs in the model. Scopes are just syntactic sugar for class methods.

Comment: Scopes *are* class methods and ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments). So according to the official Rails guides, your `published` scope should be implemented directly as a class method (i.e. `def self.published`).

Comment: @max yes that's serializer. So when to put methods within serializer? I think I can do the same thing with putting methods into serializer or scope/AR class method to output narrowing results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) documentation:

> Unlike Shirt.find(...), however, the object returned by Shirt.red is
>   not an Array but an ActiveRecord::Relation, which is composable with
>   other scopes; it resembles the association object constructed by a
>   has_many declaration. For instance, you can invoke Shirt.red.first,
>   Shirt.red.count, Shirt.red.where(size: 'small'). Also, just as with
>   the association objects, named scopes act like an Array, implementing
>   Enumerable; Shirt.red.each(&block), Shirt.red.first, and
>   Shirt.red.inject(memo, &block) all behave as if Shirt.red really was
>   an array.

Basically, using a scope is more flexible. Personally, I'd start by using a scope, and fall back to using a class method if using scope causes an edge case problem.